# two servers at the same time in the same -> ANGULAR 4 IN 4200 an Node Express IN 3000

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

How can I run an angular server 4 and another node express at the same time in the same port? 
I tried using the proxy and the statics ways.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way two processes can read from the same port. It is simply not technically possible. But you could still achieve something similar... The trick is to add a third process, this process would listen to the port you want (we'll call it front), while your 2 servers listen on their own ports (we'll call them privates). The process listening to the front port will then receive all the requests and forward them to the right port depending on which application needs to handle the request.

This method is called reverse proxy, one entry point, many endpoint.

So now you'd need a way to know if a request wants the angular app, or the express app... Either by using sub domains, sub path, or something of the sort. You could use NGINX, which is pretty fast and good at that, it could even be used to serve your static assets which might be better than using NodeJS for those.

Now, since StackOverflow is not a forum or a place to ask broad questions, I suggest you use the info I provided to search a bit on your side, and come back to us with more specific question, either when you try to configure your reverse proxy or to find the best method to identify where to send the request...

Comment: Thanks!! @Salketer, i`m going to search more information

Answer (score 0):

in package.json:

```
"start": "concurrently \"node server\" \"ng serve --env=dev --port 443 --host 0.0.0.0 --live-reload false --ssl true --ssl-cert '...' --ssl-key '...' --proxy-config proxy.conf.json\"",
```